# Gtk primary key

Tags: linux, osx, gtk, gtk3, gtk2

Is there any way to setup Gtk applications under Linux to force use `Super` as primary modifier, instead of `Control`. I tried `gtk-key-theme-name=Mac` for both *gtk2* and *gtk3* without success, also I found `GTK_DEFAULT_ACCEL_MOD_MASK` in *gtk2* sources, but can't find nothing similar for latest *gtk3*. Any suggestion, maybe some patches available?